# To show that gcd (a,b) ,gcd (b,c),gcd (c,d),gcd (c,a)=1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose 91 distinct positive integers greater than 1 are given such that there are at least 456 pairs, among them which are relatively prime. Show that one can find four integers a, b, c, d among
them such that gcd (a, b) = gcd (b, c) = gcd (c, d) = gcd (d, a) = 1.

My approach was to use number theory ,initually I used the theorems on HCF to prove,Eulers theorem and all,but failed.
A rigorous proof is needed

Comment: Do $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ have to be different? Because the excercise is trivial if you use $a=c$ and $b=d$: You can just take $a$ and $b$ from one of the 456 pairs and are done.

Comment: @Kaligule They may be different...as we need to generalise it

Comment: @Kaligule ...Yes... It's trivial if you take what you said... But as far as I know this is a Olympiad problem.... So a bit rigorous proof is need

Comment: I wrote a more wordy proof down as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take one pair $(a,b)$ from the $456$ mentioned pairs. Then $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, which means that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Now choose $c=a$ and $d=b$. The resulting four intergers $a,b,c,d$ fullfill the requirements as they are all among the $91$ integers and:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\gcd(a,b)&=&1 \\
\gcd(b,c)&=&\gcd(b,a)=1 \\
\gcd(c,d)&=&\gcd(a,b)=1 \\
\gcd(d,a)&=&\gcd(b,a)=1
\end{eqnarray} $$

qed

Comment: Your reasoning is not true... This problem is done using PHP

Comment: @user854451 resoning can't be true or untrue, it can be correct or incorrect. What in the reasoning do you think to be incorrect? And what do you mean by PHP? The programming language?